# Декомпиляция программы на C#

Tags: c#, wpf, декомпиляция

Можно ли после применения Net Reflector и получения исходного кода программы, использовать редактор формы, если декомпилируемой программой было WinForm приложение?

Сейчас я не вижу редактор формы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Обновление**

Новая версия дизайнера Windows Forms (Visual Studio 2015) стала умнее, и разбирает код за вас (смотрите ответ @Sergey Rufanov).

В ней редактирование должно работать без дополнительных усилий. Что, кстати, очень сложно с точки зрения имплементации.

Оставшаяся часть ответа относится к старым версиям Visual Studio.

---

Нет.

Декомпиляторы восстанавливают код — и только это является их задачей. Они не восстановят исходный код приложения, они лишь найдут исходный код, который будет компилироваться в такой же (или примерно такой же) файл. Вот [обсуждение вопроса](https://forums.reflector.net/questions/1648/decompiling-to-form-design-mode-with-code-too.html) на форуме поддержки Рефлектора.

Они не восстанавливают внутреннюю структуру файлов, нужную для Forms Editor'а, не восстанавливают комментарии и имена внутренних переменных, не разбивают классы на partial-части, как этого хочет Windows Forms Editor.

Вам придётся разобраться, как устроен код, который требует Forms Editor, и привести декомпилированный код к этому виду вручную. Посмотрите, как [справился с задачей](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/11/reverse-compiling-windows-forms.html) Stephen Cleary, он описывает, какие изменения в коде проводил он.

Никто не говорил, что reverse engineering — лёгкая задача.

Comment: Не требует студия того, что вы указали. Текущей версии достаточно наличия класса-наследника Form. А как этот класс создавали - абсолютно не важно.

Comment: @VladD, Sergey Rufanov - прав.

Answer (score 4):

Да, конечно. Практически все текущие версии существующих декомпиляторов нормально восстанавливают формы, в том числе и упомянутый вами .Net Reflector

Comment: А как я могу получить форму? Вот я декомпильнул прогу, а форм нигде не вижу...

Comment: @iluxa1810, Добавляете приложение в Reflector, щелкой правой кнопки на сборке, выбираете "Export Source Code", открываете проект в Visual Studio, дважды шелкаете по классу формы в студии - появляется редактор этой формы.

Comment: @iluxa1810, Возможно у вас старая студия. В 2010-й, например. редактор форм ломался при любом отклонении от нормы. В 2015 же редактор форм сжирает что угодно благодоря Roslyn - главное что бы у вас в файле был класс-наследник Form - Reflector же это вполне себе обеспечивает.

Comment: Хм. А как насчёт partial-классов, наподобие тех, что находятся в designer.cs? Они больше не обязательны?

Comment: @VladD, да, именно так - сейчас они совершенно не обязательны.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov: Круто, Roslyn рулит.

Comment: @VladD, если правильно помню, в 2012 и 2013-х студиях c пакетом Roslyn это тоже поддерживалось. Жаль что MS недавно убрала этот пакет со словами "релиз 2015 уже совсем-совсем скоро, хотите roslyn - переходите на нее". =/ Отличный вариант для плавного перехода был.